# "Broken pipe" when uploading files to S3 via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have a directory of M4V files (each around 1 GB) on my machine that I want to upload to my S3 bucket. I decided to try the AWS CLI so I can execute a command and let my computer do the rest, but it doesn’t seem to work.

The command I’m issuing is:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://yourfightsite-vod/videos/output/m4v --recursive --acl private
```

But running this command returns output like the following:

> upload failed: ./54cffd1ad106d.m4v to s3://yourfightsite-vod/videos/output/m4v/54cffd1ad106d.m4v
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='yourfightsite-vod.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /videos/output/m4v/54cffd1ad106d.m4v?partNumber=4&uploadId=oG.0CBqIpsRcxO.ZqLIgOOBi8g9JFOKD8wQrmrNFa6Cx9LvGY9_PXiqaaVm6X3fIzXbCor8QSMEeqCfovtivHNFVyea8UNoxrVTpTEvM3ibGBxF30HGPkrxWuA83k6gj (Caused by : Errno 32 Broken pipe)

What does this mean? What is a “broken pipe” and how can I rectify this so my uploads are successful?

Comment: add `--debug` before `s3`, paste that output in your question.

Answer (score 3):

> What is a “broken pipe” and how can I rectify this so my uploads are
>   successful?

"Broken Pipe" means you've lost your connection.    It could be a problem on Amazon's side, could be a problem on your side... who knows....  the point is that you were communicating, and now you are not.

Best resolution is to use multi-part uploads.  In their own documentation, Amazon recommend that you use [multi-part uploads](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) for large files over 100MB. It looks like the CLI tool might be using this already.

The second half of the resolution is for your code to catch and handle errors such as this gracefully (i.e. retry a couple of times and then ring alarm bells).

Comment: I’m not sure this relates to the CLI utility I’m using, as stated in the question. From my understanding, the CLI *should* upload large objects in multiple parts.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it might be (partNumber=4&).... but it looks like the CLI utility is poorly coded and is not handling errors gracefully !  The main point of my answer remains the same.... you have lost your connection, you should be retrying that upload (or part upload).

Answer (score 3):

Just sharing my experience!
I know it's a bit late, but yesterday I found myself facing the same problem even after a whole year running the same configuration without any problem.
Some files would get uploaded where others were not. There was no pattern...
Using the --debug option, for those files that missed the upload, there was a warning about the wrong region. So, I changed the region in my s3cmd configuration and it was fixed!

Comment: it's works for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a new line character (\n) in AWS bucket URL.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while using aws cli with access keys no more attached to any user. To solve this I just replaced access credentials with a valid one.